# Adding rows with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, operators, sum

I have a table in MySQL called users for example, in that users table there are two rows which contain a numeric value in which I wish to add together.

For arguments sake lets say, this is the table structure

```
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ROW    | Numeric1 | Numberic2
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      ROW 1|       38 | 39
      ROW 2|       41 | 54
      ROW 3|       47 | 41
      ROW 4|       73 | 37
      ROW 5|       31 | 25
```

I wish to add the Numeric row 1 and numeric row 2 together and then add it to the next one, so the result would return 426 (the total sum of all of the numbers) using PHP and then echoing the value.

For some reason I cannot use

```
    $total = $numeric1 + numberic2;
    echo $total;
```

Any ideas in how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you get it by query `SELECT sum(Numeric1)+sum(Numeric2) FROM mytable`???

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT indvsum.sum1 + indvsum.sum2
FROM (SELECT SUM(numeric1) AS sum1,
             SUM(numeric2) AS sum2
      FROM tablename) indvsum
```

indvsum is just an alias to the inner table.

Comment: That works when issuing through a mysql statement which is nice, how would I echo this in PHP?

Comment: $total = mysql_query(<above query>); This will give you the final output.

Comment: When I do that it echos "Resource id #4"

Comment: To get selected rows use mysql_fetch_array($result) or mysql_fetch_row($result)